# Can I include global static member?

Tags: c++, static, include, global

There are few global variables which are static in one of the header files. I see these variables are used in the associated .cc files. So, looks like this has no issues.

My questions are:

- Whats the difference between including a global variable vs static global variable ?
  I know static global doesnt have visibility outside its file. But dont know how this would work when it comes as part of a .h which is #included.
- I wrote a sample program, and tried the same thing. But, I get compilation error the moment I make the variable static. When it is just global, it is fine.
  So, is there something which I am missing on a regular g++ build ? (Please note, the initial case was on our official code base which has enough makefiles, .h files and all).

Thanks for the help !

Here is my sample program :

.h file:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned int uint;

static const int appk=189;

class abc1
{
    public:
        abc1(int x);
        virtual void printVal();

};
```

.cc file:

```
#include "abc1.h"

extern int appk;

abc1::abc1(int x)
{

}

void abc1::printVal()
{
    printf("abc1 print: %d\n", appk);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) If you put a global variable in a `.h` file and include it in various .cpp/.cc files then it will be defined multiple times for every file. So you are most like to get a **linker error**.
To overcome that, mostly you are likely to use `extern` keyword:

```
// myfile.h
extern int i;
```

and define that in only one translation unit:

```
// somefile.cc
int i;
```

(2) If you put a `static` global in a `.h` file and include it, then you will not get any error, because for every **different translation unit**, there will be a different copy for that `static` global variable.

```
// myfile.h
static int i;  // creates a unique and unrelated copy in all .cc file where included
```

However, such usage is **deprecated**; instead of that it's better to use unnamed `namespace`:

```
namespace {
  int i;
}
```

From your question, I don't see that you should get any linker error for `static` global.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell your compilation error without code, but if you have a header that declares a static global, then you just create that global variable independently and separately in each translation unit that includes the header.

Example:

header.h:

```
#ifndef H_XXX
#define H_XXX

static int a;

#endif
```

file1.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"

// now have access to a variable called "a"
```

file2.cpp:

```
#include "header.h"

// now also have access to some "a"
```

The two files both have access to a global variable called `a`, but each file has its own separate copy, private to its translation unit, which is not visible outside.

For a practical example, I think `cout` is declared as a static global, so everyone who uses `<iostream>` gets their own copy.

Comment: Why do you say `extern int appk;` again in the source file? Get rid of that! Also, global constants are implicitly static - you only need the `static` keyword for global non-consts.

Comment: Compilation passes, but the value comes as 0

Answer (score 1):

`static` variable has internal-linkage. What it means is that if you have a static variable `a` in `x.h` and you include `x.h` in two files say `m.cpp` and `n.pp` then each of these two files gets its own copy of `a` which means if you change its value in `m.cpp`, then `n.cpp` is not going  to see that change, because there exists two variables with same name in each translation unit (.cpp). And they're independent of each other.

But if `a` is not static, then including `x.h` in more than one files, you will get multiple-definition error, because each inclusion of `x.h` will try to define `a`, but since `a` is not static; it has external linkage now, which means if its defined in `m.cpp`, then you will get error when including `x.h` in `n.cpp` (or vice-versa). In this case, you've to write `x.h` as:

```
//x.h
extern int a;
```

And then define `a` in exactly one `.cpp` file, either `m.cpp` or `n.cpp`, but not both. Say its `m.cpp`.

```
//m.cpp
#include "x.h"

int a =10;
```

And you're done. Now you can include `x.h` in as many `.cpp` file as you want, and can access `a`, modify its value, do whatever you want. Any change to it, will be seen by all `.cpp` files now.